# Plural or singular verb when subject is separated by a comma?

Tags: grammatical-number

In a sentence when subject is separated by a comma, we use there plural verb or singular verb? There are no conjunction like *and, as well as* in between. Like I have one sentence as :

> Too much cricket, too many teams to lead ***have/has*** left Dhoni jaded.

Here Dhoni is the name of a person.

I think **have** would sound more appropriate in this context as here comma denote **and** implicitly.  But I am not sure. Please clear up my confusion about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the conjunction (and) is not explicit, it is understood. There are two simple sentences combined into one. So the verb will be plural.

> Too much cricket has left Dhoni jaded.
>
> (Having) too many teams to lead has left Dhoni jaded.

Hence, all of these demands taken together **have** reduced the ability of M S Dhoni to perform at his best.

Comment: If the sentence was like that: **I, you and Jeetendra have/has to work hard in order to meet the project deadline.** 
Then what would be more appropriate?

Comment: @Sudhir Conjunctive *and* always creates a plural subject, and plural subjects take plural verbs. Only with disjunctives is the picture more complicated.