# Use of "proven"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am wondering if the following sentence is grammatically correct.

> The feasibility of algorithm A and the high performance of algorithm B is proven by a number of experiments.

I would like to avoid using "are demonstrated" instead of "is proven" due to word repetition. However, I am not sure if it should be "are proven", or "is proven" in this context.

**Check the comments for the answer to this question**

Comment: These coordinated elements are disparate, so a plural verb form is needed. In fact, I'd prefer separate sentences, I think. // 'Proven' is a largely Scottish usage; I'd repeat 'demonstrated' or use 'shown'.

Comment: Repetition in technical writing is not a bad thing. If it's in the kitchen, it's definitely not in the garage, so just say kitchen each time. A demonstrates B, X demonstrates Y. If you write that X proves Y, some reader will wonder *Proves, but does not demonstrate Y?*

Comment: Or 'verified'. Say what the experiments actually *did*. If you are discussing algorithms, perhaps 'proof' implies 'formal proof'. Can 'feasibility' (of something not yet achieved) and 'performance' (of something achieved) be used in the comparison of two different algorithms?

Comment: A number of experiments prove the feasibility of algorithm A and the high performance of algorithm B. [sigh]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular verb after two noun phrases joined by "and" that can be thought of as a single thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97459/singular-verb-after-two-noun-phrases-joined-by-and-that-can-be-thought-of-as-a). See also [Plural or singular verb when plural subject is separated by an "and"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521554) for links to a number of similar questions.

Comment: For an elaboration of Mr. Baskin's comment, see [Using synonyms to improve text readability ("elegant variation")](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/538639).

Comment: Thanks for your help! @jsw29 your link is really useful. It appears that "is proven" is grammatically correct, agree?

Comment: @David, both are **grammatically** correct; 'is proven' is apt **if** A and B are sufficiently strongly connected that they can/should be thought of as one 'thing'. Whether this is so is not matter of grammar.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answers my question!

Answer (score 1):

Compound subjects are plural. If the subject part of a sentence refers to more than one subject, than it is plural, even if the subjects are joined by a conjunction.

https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-styleguide/chapter/subject-verb-agreement/

Comment: This rather oversimplifies the matter. As can be seen from the answers to the question that this is a duplicate of, the use of singular/plural in such cases depends on whether the subject is thought of as 'one thing' (with two components) or as two relatively independent things. Without knowing the context in which the OP's sentence appears, and what it is really about, one cannot say whether it calls for the singular or the plural form of the verb.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your very useful comments. My thinking was that the experiments prove the first part of the sentence. This is why I would use "is proven" - is it correct?